# HierarchyId in Clean Architecture

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, clean-architecture, hierarchyid

I want to migrate an existing .NET project to the Clean Architecture model but the current EF Core entities are using the HierarchyId data type (from the EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.HierarchyId package).

This type provides features that are useful even as domain entities (like the path of the node in the tree, the GetLevel() method, etc.)

How am I supposed to handle this if the core project has no dependency on EF Core?

Comment: As usual - create your own type and map between them.

Comment: That means reimplementing a big part of HierarchyId... Do you have examples of the kind of mapping you're talking about? I'm a beginner on Clean Architecture.

Comment: Quote from [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/hierarchyid?tabs=netcore-cli): HierarchyId is designed to work with EF Core, but it can also be used outside of EF Core in other applications. The Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Abstractions package doesn't reference any other packages, and so has minimal impact on deployed application size and dependencies. - So just use this type.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Yes, that's what I do for the moment but this package is specific to SQL Server and that's the kind of dependency that is supposed to be in the infrastructure project of a Clean Architecture solution. Hence my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of reimplementing the entire functionality of the HierarchyId data type, you can create your own simplified representation of hierarchical data within your domain layer. This can be achieved by defining a custom type or class that encapsulates the hierarchical information relevant to your application.

For example, you could define a `HierarchyNode` class with properties such as `Id`, `ParentId`, and `Level`, which represent the hierarchical structure of your data. Here's a basic example of how you could implement such a class:

```cs
public class HierarchyNode
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    // additional properties
}
```

Next, you'll need to map between your `HierarchyNode` class and the HierarchyId data type when interacting with your database. This can be done using mapping methods or utilities within your infrastructure layer. For example, when retrieving data from the database, you would map the HierarchyId values to instances of your `HierarchyNode` class, and vice versa when storing data.

Here's a simplified example of how you could perform mapping between your custom type and the HierarchyId data type:

```cs
public static class HierarchyMapper
{
    public static HierarchyNode MapFromHierarchyId(HierarchyId hierarchyId)
    {
        // Implement logic to map HierarchyId to HierarchyNode
        // Example:
        return new HierarchyNode
        {
            Id = hierarchyId.Value,
            ParentId = hierarchyId.GetAncestor().Value,
            Level = hierarchyId.GetLevel()
        };
    }

    public static HierarchyId MapToHierarchyId(HierarchyNode node)
    {
        return HierarchyId.Parse($"/{node.Id}/"); 
    }
}
```

Using these mapping methods, you can seamlessly integrate hierarchical data into your Clean Architecture project without the need to directly manipulate the HierarchyId data type within your domain layer.

I hope this provides a helpful starting point for implementing mapping between your own type and the HierarchyId data type. If you have any further questions or need clarification, feel free to ask.

UPD:

Use a `ValueConverter` to map between your custom type (`HierarchyNode`) and the `HierarchyId` data type

```cs
public class HierarchyNodeConverter : ValueConverter<HierarchyNode, HierarchyId>
{
    public HierarchyNodeConverter() : base(
        v => v != null ? HierarchyId.Parse($"/{v.Id}/") : default,
        v => v != null ? new HierarchyNode { Id = v.Value, ParentId = v.GetAncestor().Value, Level = v.GetLevel() } : null)
    { }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder
        .Entity<YourEntity>()
        .Property(e => e.NodePath)
        .HasConversion(new HierarchyNodeConverter());
}
```

For Complex Queries consider using stored procedures or raw SQL queries.

```cs
var result = context.YourEntities
    .FromSqlRaw("SELECT * FROM YourEntities WHERE NodePath.IsDescendantOf({0})", manager.HierarchyIdParameter)
    .ToList();
```

This will execute the SQL directly, leveraging the database's capabilities for efficient hierarchical operations.

Comment: How would you integrate the mapping with EF Core? Should it be a ValueConverter? Also, how do you deal with queries that leverage the hierarchyid data type at SQL level for performance? For example, context.Employees.Where(x => x.NodePath.IsDescendantOf(manager)) or more complex queries.

Comment: Yes you should use ValueConverter to map between your custom type (HierarchyNode) and the HierarchyId data type.


I'll drop an example of that mapper, under my answer.